# How to run websocket server on mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, websocket

I want two-way communication between a web app and a native app running on the same smartphone. I thought I could use websockets (is this a good idea?). But I would need to set up a websocket server in the app. Is this possible? Is there a cross-platform javascript-centric way to achieve this in both iOS and Android?

I've looked at the https://github.com/websockets/ws project. It states that it cannot set up a server in the browser, but could it work in a mobile app?

Comment: That's an interesting question! What sort of communication do you need to achieve? Can you route the traffic to a server that isn't running on the device?

Comment: Using a backend server is my fallback option, but my ideal is to communicate directly between clients, mostly for speed. I want the app to be used for authenticating and confirming an action in the browser.

Comment: What are your requirements in terms of network topology?

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean. Everything is local, the web app is running in mobile safari (or Chrome), the native iOS app is running on the same device.